# example of a Lie algebra L and its non-semisimple representation

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

What is an example of a Lie algebra L and its non-semisimple representation? I need this for study so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would $L=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and its Verma module of highest weight zero be useful for you?

Comment: Actually, for most purposes, the module I have in mind is described [in this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3340049/11619).

Comment: I am not exactly sure what a Verma module is in all honesty. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: That's fine. Verma modules come a bit later in the course. For the time being you can take a look at the representation in the post I linked to. It is an infinite dimensional representation, and its only submodule has codimension one. There is no matching 1-dimensional submodule, so that representation is not semisimple. As you tagged the question [tag:semisimple-lie-algebras] I assume that you want $L$ to be semisimple. In that case all non-semisimple representations are necessarily infinite dimensional.

Comment: In the thread Dietrich Burde linked to, there is a finite-dimensional non-semisimple representation. But in that example $L$ is not semisimple. You could actually clarify the question in that regard. Do you expect $L$ to be semisimple, or do you not care about that as long as it has a non-semisimple representation?

Comment: Oh yes, I meant for L to be a semisimple Lie algebra. @JyrkiLahtonen